# How to uninstall a software that has been installed using wine?

Tags: wine

I have installed Ms Office 7 using wine, I need to install office 10.
can someone tell me how can i uninstall office 7?

Answer (score 9):

You can use Uninstaller.

> Uninstaller is a GUI uninstaller for all setup programs that put an
>   uninstall entry in the registry, e.g. InstallShield or the WISE
>   installer. It's similar in function to "Add/Remove Programs" in
>   Windows, except much simpler.
>
> An actual Add/Remove Programs control panel applet (appwiz.cpl) was
>   added to Wine 1.1.2, and the existing uninstaller was replaced with a
>   stub to launch this control panel in Wine 1.1.3.
>
> The uninstaller does not work with programs installed with an .msi
>   file.
>
> ```
>  wine uninstaller
> ```
>
> For versions of Wine before 1.1.16 (which includes 1.0.x), you can
>   also use the wrapper in /usr/bin/:
>
> `uninstaller`<sup>1</sup>

<sup><sup>**1**</sup>Source:[WineHQ](http://wiki.winehq.org/uninstaller)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I think there is uninstall.exe (or something like this of installed program). Open it via wine and run it. I think this will works.

Answer (score -1):

Run below command:

```
wine uninstaller
```