# How to uninstall a wine software?

Tags: wine, uninstall

I will start by saying this is not a duplicate of [Uninstall a program installed with Wine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/101064/uninstall-a-program-installed-with-wine) nor [How to uninstall a software that has been installed using wine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/185198/how-to-uninstall-a-software-that-has-been-installed-using-wine). I already "STFW" as adviced in the [how to ask](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask) guide.
I've installed plenty of software using wine. However I want to get ride of a lot of it (**not all**). When I access the Wine Uninstaller I am able to uninstall the programs and then, they are back (Including that misterious and annoying program highligthed).
[image: Add/Remove programs]

#### I have tried deleting the programs from the "C:/ Drive" and also I have tried what is stated in the [How to delete Wine Programs?](http://www.ehow.com/how_7378611_delete-wine-programs.html) Guide.

Comment: Have you check if you are using the same prefix to uninstall your programs that the one where the programs are installed ?

Comment: @MrVaykadji Yes sir.

Comment: When you say "I have tried deleting in c:/", do you mean in `~/.wine/drive_c/Program \Files` ? If you did so, are any files in that directory ? If there are any files, that means they are uninstalled, but you still have the shortcuts (and probably the registry keys). It could help to know^^

Comment: That is what I mean, and yes, there was information there that I have deleted already.

Comment: And they are not there anymore ? Say, for example, you want to uninstall Microsoft Office, you deleted the files in `~/.wine/drive_c/Program \Files`. You now can't run Microsoft Office, but you still have the shortcuts ? ||| So that we're clear : you want to remove the shortcuts and the registry keys.

Comment: @MrVaykadji yeah, let's say that I want to uninstall MSOffice, I ran the wine uninstaller and uninstalled it; I can't access it anymore nor on the unity dash or anyway. I access _ ~/.wine/drive_c/Program \Files_ and there are files which I delete.  
However when I access the Wine uninstaller the MSOffice entry appears there (and the annoying set of characters highlighted in the picture).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solve by downloading [Revo Uninstaller Portable](http://www.revouninstaller.com/download-free-portable.php):

Uninstall every program in *Moderate Mode*. Delete every Registry Key and any file or folder. Restart the program everytime.

### Note:

Can't find a way to delete the misterious program highlgthed in the *question image*.